# How can I use Capybara with Cucumber-jvm and Java?

Tags: java, cucumber, capybara, cucumber-jvm, webrat

I learned about cucumber and capybara while using Ruby on Rails, and I love it. Automated testing of manual inputs like button clicks is a must have for me.

However, now that I am working with Java, I do not know how to include Capybara/webrat into my project. I am able to use cucumber-jvm really nicely, but I really would like to integrate capybara.

Can anyone here guide me on how to use Capybara in my Java project?

Comment: It's very simple. you can't.

Comment: Is there an alternative software with the same features of Capybara? I'm finding things like HTMLUnit on google but I'm open to a suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Webdriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/), the evolution of Selenium - it allows you to interact with websites nicely.

Answer (score -1):

You can always start with JRuby.